# bitbake embedded linux docker container with asp.net core binaries x86_64

Tags: c#, .net, linux, docker, containers

Using bitbake I am making an embedded linux image and copying/shipping asp.net core runtime binaries in it.
dotnet --info command working fine inside container but it is not executing project dll files. When running dotnet NetCore.Docker.dll it stuck and there is no output. I tried with file, debug and Console.WriteLine, see below.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
namespace NetCore.Docker
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var counter = 0;
            var max = args.Length != 0 ? Convert.ToInt32(args[0]) : -1;
            
            string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"file.txt", lines);
            
            while (max == -1 || counter < max)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Counter: {++counter}");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Debug Counter: {++counter}");
                await Task.Delay(3000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Microsoft provided pre-build docker images.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=linux

Using above link, I have tested it and also copy the same environment variables and publish folder in my embedded linux container but no progress. I need to know what Microsoft docker container have other then asp.net core runtime binaries. Apparent difference is linux.

Inside microsoft container

```
$uname -a
Linux 9deb13801df3 4.15.0-118-generic #119~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 8 14:54:40 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Inside my embedded linux container

```
$uname -a
Linux 991873bd82e0 4.14.68-intel-pk-standard #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 6 19:57:04 PKT 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I tried many things, like executing bash into container $docker exec -it [container id] /bin/bash and then manually run $dotnet NetCore.Docker.dll but nothing happens. Running $dotnet --info gives proper result.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to build docker image using yocto bitbake Rocko distribution with .NET framework precompiled binaries Version: 3.1.8.

Later on, I figure it out that it works on yocto Thud distribution. This means .NET framework Version: 3.1.8 binaries are not compatible with Rocko linux distribution.